# Initial Map view and zoom level

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm new to Android. I made an app with a `MapView` and I would like to set that when I run my app it shows a defined location (town) with a defined zoom level. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Be more specific. Maps API v1 or v2? One would assume from your tag it is API v2.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this:

```
MapController mc;
    GeoPoint p;
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
 mc = mapView.getController();
        String coordinates[] = {"1.352566007", "103.78921587"};// Change this value to your desire position.
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

        p = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (lat * 1E6), 
            (int) (lng * 1E6));

        mc.animateTo(p); // set map center to your desire place
        mc.setZoom(17); //set zoom level.
        mapView.invalidate();
```

You can use this [page](http://universimmedia.pagesperso-orange.fr/geo/loc.htm) to get place's long/lat

Comment: That is for maps API v1. The OP's tag refers to v2.